# STM32: Combine two comparator outputs

Tags: stm32, comparator

I have a STM32L072KB microcontroller and want to combine two analog signals (they represent a kind of "quadrature encoded signal" with a 50% duty cycle) into one "combined digital output signal", which have the doubled frequency (for my purpose the doubled output signal is used to provide the doubled accuracy):

[image]

I am using the both comparator peripherals COMP1 and COMP2 for detecting the signal edges and it works fine to configure them that they directly relay the COMPX_OUTs to a predefined, but for each comparator separate and fixed GPIO (without any SW/ISR delay):
[image]

- COMP1_OUT -> PA11
- COMP2_OUT -> PA12

Due to my HW layout, I want to realize something like this configuration:

- COMP1_OUT ⊕ COMP2_OUT -> PA11

  or
- COMP1_OUT ⊕ COMP2_OUT -> PA12

I have not found a way to directly connect both comparator outputs into one single output pin without introducing an SW/ISR delay/latency. I read that some general purpose timers offer a so called "Hall" encoder mode, which supports XOR-ing up to 3 input signals. But since connecting a Timer directly to a GPIO via DMA seems to be impossible on a STM32L0-core, I have no idea how to implement this...

Does anyone know a "hardware/fast way" to route/XOR simultaneously both COMP_OUTs to a single GPIO output pin (either PA11 or PA12) or is it in that case inevitable, to use an ISR-based solution?

Comment: How's that a programming problem?

Comment: I think this should be possible by properly configure the uC with the ST HAL and apply something like a trick whiche uses a combination of Timer/PWM/DMA... capabilities?! But I am just a novice on programming the STM32, so yes, I am not 100% sure if this is programmatically possible to implement, but I hope so.

Comment: You should rather try that on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Really? I thought electronics.stackexchange.com would more focus on the HW engineering part, and not how to proper setup the uC with the HAL by the firmware?